# Trouble creating custom routes in Ruby on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby, routes, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't seem to set up a custom URL.  All the RESTful routes work fine, but I can't figure out how to simply add `/:unique_url` to the existing routes, which I create in the model (a simple 4 character random string) and will serve as the "permalink" of sorts.

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :treks
match ':unique_url' => 'treks#mobile'
```

**Controller**

```
.
.
def mobile
  @trek = trek.find(params[:id])
end
```

Is this because I'm trying to define a custom action on an existing resource?  Can I not create custom methods on the same controller as one with a resource?

*By the way, when I change `routes.rb` to `match 'treks/:id/:unique_url' => treks#mobile` it works fine, but I just want the url to simply be `/:unique_url`*

**Update** *It seems like `find_by_[parameter]` is the way to go...*

I've been playing in console and I can't seem to get any methods to come forward...I can run `Trek.last.fullname` for example, but cannot run `@trek = Trek.last`...and then call...`@trek.lastname` for example.  Any clues why?  I think this is my issue.

Comment: Your `mobile` method uses `params[:id]` but you don't have the `:id` in your route. You'll need to create a `find_by_unique_url` method in your model (if you don't have it already) and use it in your `mobile` method.

Comment: thanks mark, where do i create this method?

Comment: If you have a `unique_url` field then you have it already. In a rails console you can do `Trek.find_by_unique_url(url)` where `url` is a matching unique_url, and you'll see a result.

Comment: when i run this in the console, it says undefined method...i think can't seem to get `find_by_unique_url` to work.  does it have to be somewhere in my model?

Comment: @MarkThomas can you check out my update...i think this may be the cause of the issue...thanks!

Comment: You've already accepted an answer to this question. If you have another question, please start a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trek.find_by_unique_url( params[:unique_url] ) # should do the trick
```

@pruett no, the `find_by_XXX` methods are generated on-the-fly via Ruby's method_missing call!  So instead of XXX you can use any of the attributes which you defined in a model.

You can even go as far as listing multiple attributes, such as:

```
find_by_name_and_unique_url( the_name, the_unigue_url)
```

Check these pages:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

---

if you get a `undefined method ... for nil:NilClass` , it means that the object you are trying to call that method on does not exist, e.g. is nil.

You probably just missed to put an if-statement before that line to make sure the object is non-nil

Comment: i don't know what it was...could it be i was hitting a typo the whole time???? anyways...seems to be working now.  i think my attribute `unique_url` was constantly changing on every refresh, so i was chasing a moving target, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So is there a field on Trek which stores its unique url? If so you should be doing something like this:

```
@trek = Trek.find_by_url(params[:unique_url])
```

Comment: i have a field `:unique_url` which i create in a callback `before_save` function.

Comment: So in that case it would be `trek.find_by_unique_url(params[:unique_url])`

Comment: @pruett no, the `find_by_XXX` methods are generated on-the-fly via Ruby's method_missing call!  So instead of XXX you can use any of the attributes which you defined in a model

Comment: hmm...i have that now in my controller...but it doesn't seem to work.  i'm getting `undefined method 'fullname' for nil:NilClass` (fullname) is another property of my model that I'm calling by `<%= @trek.fullname %>` in my view

Comment: Indeed, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base under "Dynamic attribute-based finders". 

You can also do `Trek.where(:unique_url => params[:unique_url])[0]`, does the same thing

Comment: You're getting a nil because no Trek has been found for that unique url.

Comment: @AlexPeattie i keep getting nil even tho they are in the development db

Comment: Hmm not sure why that would be, but sounds like a separate issue - consider opening a new question

Answer (score -1):

Hmm. I usually would do something like this:

```
map.connect "/:unique_url", :controller => "treks", :action => "mobile"
```

Then in that controller the ID isn't going to be applicable.. you'd need to change it to something like this:

```
def mobile
  @trek = trek.find_by_unique_url(params[:unique_url])
end
```

(that's if unique_url is the column to search under)

Comment: Hah.. yeah most of my apps are still stuck in 2.3.. haven't gotten all the new stuff down yet.